scesim file does not update its dmn model information when the model changes
when I update my model in the kie dmn editor extension for vscode the scesim file can't pick up the change.
If I have two models I can switch from one and back to the original and the scesim gets updated.
Is there a better way to do this. If I only have one dmn I can't do this trick

I found a workaround.  You have to close the editor and reopen it.
